# ubuntu 20.04 error undefined symbol: FT_Property_Set

Tags: python

There was a python2 project which was working fine on Ubuntu 16.04, but when i created virtualenv to set-up the project for python2 all is working fine except PDF generation error via using python pdfkit module

/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/ls -ld : undefined symbol: FT_Property_Set

```
$ wkhtmltopdf --version 
wkhtmltopdf 0.12.5
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf 
wkhtmltopdf: /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf
$ ldd /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf | grep local 
libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/local/freetype/2_10_1/lib/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007faf8693a000)

$ sudo find / -type f -name *freetype*.so* 2> /dev/null  
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/128/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6.15.0
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6.15.0
/home/me/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/opencv_python.libs/libfreetype-8d3bcff4.so.6.14.0
/home/me/Downloads/freetype/freetype-2.10.1/objs/.libs/libfreetype.so.6.17.1
/home/me/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.0/lib/node_modules/framework7-cli/node_modules/sharp/vendor/lib/libfreetype.so.6.17.1
/home/me/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libfreetype.so.6
/usr/local/freetype/2_10_1/lib/libfreetype.so.6.17.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6.17.1
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/vlc/plugins/text_renderer/libfreetype_plugin.so
/work/mine/lamp74/common/lib/libfreetype.so.6.8.0
```

Comment: Please add the following output to the question: `wkhtmltopdf --version`, `dpkg -S /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf`, `ldd /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf | grep local` , `sudo find / -type f -name *freetype*.so* 2> /dev/null` .

Comment: @N0rbert  Edited as requested

Answer (score 0):

You have locally compiled version of LibFreetype. To make things run smooth you have to remove such library and use official packaged version.

Open terminal and type:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/freetype
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libfreetype6 libfreetype-dev
```

and then retry running `wkhtmltopdf` or your Python script which uses it.

Comment: followed but did not work, However wkhtmltopdf was working fine with command line, but was not working with django request page.  

Read somewhere, It might be failed dynamically load by QT lib., Not resolved yet.

used with:
Django==1.6.7
Pillow>=2.4.0
argparse>=1.2.1
chardet>=2.2.1
pdfkit>=0.4.1
python-magic>=0.4.6

even though i compared the python2 pdfkit lib latest and installed are same, no-diff, still getting this issue.

Comment: You have to carefully inspect your environment. To exclude possible problems caused by files in your home-folder you can try the test method on newly created user profile.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually It`s resolved after several days.

Nothing caused by the home file folder. This is actual caused of QT lib dynamically loading issue. After several setting done at system end and environment var settings , nothing works.

In end I have to Download a precompiled binary (which is QT patched) from https://wkhtmltopdf.org/ as per your OS version.

In my case was:
https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6-1/wkhtmltox_0.12.6-1.focal_amd64.deb

which landed installed at : /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf

and then after it works like charm.

Thx, @N0rbert for trying to help.

-:)